# Python program gets stuck when dealing with large integers

Tags: python, primes

I am working on a program that determines whether (2^n) - 1 (where n is an integer) is prime or not.

```
def check_prime(n):
    if n == 1:
        print("?")
    global k
    k = 0
    for i in range(2, (n - 1)):
        if n / i == n // i:
            print("/")
            k = 1
            break
    if k != 1:
        print("p")


def special_prime(a):
    b = (2 ** a) - 1
    check_prime(b)


for i in range(1, 143):
    print(i)
    check_prime(i)
    special_prime(i)
    print("\n")
```

When it gets to i = 31, it just gets stuck. I was wondering if my algorithm is too slow or if there is something else that I am missing.

Comment: What do you know about the complexity of factorizing prime numbers?

Comment: Your algorithm is too slow.